# Not able to shutdown Oracle Database ORA-01031

Tags: database, oracle

I am having trouble shutting down a local oracle database. I've googled the problem, and the SYSTEM user I am using is in the ora_dba domain, and I also noticed that I need the sqlnet.ora in my ORACLE_HOME/network/admin folder, but I do not have a network/admin folder in my oracle home. All I have is a middleware folder. I am installing all of this to be able to publish a BPEL process to a local weblogic instance, and this has taken me a little over two days just trying to get this all set up. I am starting to get a bit frustrated lol. Here's the error I am getting below:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to startup/shutdown the oracle instance you need extended privileges - Oracle database SYS privileges.
As soon as your Windows user DOMAIN\user has been granted group 'ora_dba', you are authorized on the OS-level to log into the database as user SYS.

```
C:\>sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL>show user
SQL>USER is "SYS"
SQL>shutdown immediate
```